# Код плавной прокрутки к якорю сходит с ума php js

Tags: php, javascript

Есть код плавной прокрутки к якорю и пару самообновлящиехся дивов. До первого обновления дива всё хорошо, после просто переходит по ссылке вместо того что бы двигаться к якорю. Помогите решить или найти альтернативу.

Скрипт плавного передвижения к якорю

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu-y").on("click","a", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
            top = $(id).offset().top;
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
    });
});
</script>
```

Кнопка

```
<span id="menu-y"><a href="#scrl">перейти к якорю</a></span>
```

Авто-обновляеемый див

```
<div id="refreshme"></div>
```

Скрипт авто-обновляемого дива

```
   <script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function(){
$('#refreshme').load('#refreshme');
}, 120000);
   </script>
```

Блок якоря

```
<div id="scrl"></div>
```

Comment: какая-то вложенность у этого всего есть или они все на разных уровнях?

Answer (score 3):

Первое предположение:
`#menu-y` является дочерним элементом для `#refreshme`, таким образом, когда `#refreshme` лоадит сам себя, у нас не будет отрабатывать:

```
$("#menu-y").on("click","a", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //...
}
```

Соответственно нужно заменить например на:

```
$(document).on("click","#menu-y a", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Итак, у Вас есть блок прокрутки и  блок подгрузки данных. Судя по всему, у Вас якорь как раз таки и подгружается новый каждый раз при загрузке данных (поправьте, если не так). DOM не знает о новом элементе и соответственно не вешает на него скрипт прокрутки. Самым простым и быстрым вариантом будет выделение прокрутки в отдельную функцию, которую Вы вызываете при загрузке страницы, а после обновления данных снова ее вызываете, таким образом, в DOM попадают новые данные.